# Angular JS ng-repeater not populating 2D array data

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently working on a test application. When i use the ng-repeater to populate the data, it is currently showing empty fields. However when i console.log the array, it is showing the correct data.

ORDER CONTROLLER

```
(function()
{
    var injectParams = ['$stateParams'];

    function orderController($stateParams) {
        var vm = this;

        var customerId = $stateParams.id;
        customers = [
            {
                id: 1,
                joined: '2000-12-02',
                name: 'John',
                city: 'Chandler',
                orderTotal: 9.9956,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        product: 'Shoes',
                        total: 9.9956
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                joined: '1965-01-25',
                name: 'Zed',
                city: 'Las Vegas',
                orderTotal: 19.99,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        product: 'Baseball',
                        total: 9.995
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        product: 'Bat',
                        total: 9.995
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                joined: '1944-06-15',
                name: 'Tina',
                city: 'New York',
                orderTotal: 44.99,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        product: 'Headphones',
                        total: 44.99
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                joined: '1995-03-28',
                name: 'Dave',
                city: 'Seattle',
                orderTotal: 101.50,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        product: 'Kindle',
                        total: 101.50
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        //load customers to view

        vm.orders = [];


        var result = customers;

        function loadCustomers()
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                if (result[i].id == parseInt(customerId)) 
                {
                    vm.orders.push(result[i].orders);

                }
            }
        }

        loadCustomers();

        console.log(vm.orders);
    };

    orderController.$inject = injectParams;

    angular.module('app')
    .controller('orderController', orderController);

      }());
```

ORDERS HTML

```
         <div class="row">
       <div class="small-12 columns">
        <h1>ORDERS</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="order in aT.orders">
                <td>{{ order.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ order.product }}</td>
                <td>{{ order.total }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div><!--small-12 columns-->
</div><!--row-->
```

APP.JS

```
      //Initialise Foundation

      $(document).foundation();

      //Initialise Module

      (function ()
      {

    angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])

    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
    {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/customers');

        $stateProvider
            .state('customers',
            {
                url: '/customers',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/customers.html',
                controller: 'customerController',
                controllerAs: 'aT',
            })
            .state('orders',
            {
                url: '/orders/:id',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/orders.html',
                controller: 'orderController',
                controllerAs: 'aT',
            });
       });

    }());
```

Comment: If `orders` is an array of arrays, you will need two repeaters

Comment: Could you please show me an example how i could achieve this :)

Comment: Have you added the customers array to the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `orders` is an array of arrays, you would need two repeaters. I'm not sure why you're *pushing* customer orders into `orders` as you seem to be searching by customer ID which appears to be unique among the items in `customers`. I would simply assign the value to `orders`, ie

```
var findCustomerOrders = function() {
    for (var i = 0, l = customers.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (customers[i].id == customerId) {
            return customers[i].orders;
        }
    }
    return [];
};

vm.orders = findCustomerOrders();
```

Your current template should be fine with this data.

Comment: Yet you accepted the other answer that looks nothing like your question 

Comment: sorry Phil, i must have accidentally clicked the other answer. You answer was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach your array to scope

JS:

```
// declare a module
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// configure the module.
// in this example we will create a greeting filter
app.controller('CustomerController', ['$scope', 
    function($scope) {
        $scope.customers = [
            {
                id: 1,
                joined: '2000-12-02',
                name: 'John',
                city: 'Chandler',
                orderTotal: 9.9956,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        product: 'Shoes',
                        total: 9.9956
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                joined: '1965-01-25',
                name: 'Zed',
                city: 'Las Vegas',
                orderTotal: 19.99,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        product: 'Baseball',
                        total: 9.995
                    },
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        product: 'Bat',
                        total: 9.995
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                joined: '1944-06-15',
                name: 'Tina',
                city: 'New York',
                orderTotal: 44.99,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        product: 'Headphones',
                        total: 44.99
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                joined: '1995-03-28',
                name: 'Dave',
                city: 'Seattle',
                orderTotal: 101.50,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        product: 'Kindle',
                        total: 101.50
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];
    }
]);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="CustomerController">
        <div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
            {{customer}}
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```